# SQL Query group by include array of objects

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

This is the table

[image]

This is the kind of output I want

[image]

Basically, I want to use GROUP BY for "sport", and I want an array of objects named "games" that consists of all the other sport data like id, gender, age_group and style

I am working on sequalize, so a query for sequalize will be appreciated, but if you can simply provide SQL/MySQL query, I'll try to translate it myself too.

Comment: Can you share your data as code instead of images, so it can be easy to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

First cte to get games, the second cte to get the whole element, then with a `GROUP_CONCAT` we get the json.

```
with cte as (
  SELECT 1 as row_id, sport, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('gender', gender, 'age_group', age_group, 'style', style)) games
  from mytable
  group by sport
),
cte2 as (
  SELECT row_id, sport, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('sport', sport, 'games', games)) as myObject
  from cte
  group by sport
)
select CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(trim(trailing ']' from trim(leading '[' from myObject)) SEPARATOR ', '), ']')
from cte2
GROUP BY row_id;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Nuhco9RXhJsi1muMR56zM/1)

Comment: Can you do this using Table.findAll({ ... }) ?